# Is there a way to make this query without raw part, between realtion models?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

**User Model:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var string[]
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for serialization.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    public function venues()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Venue::class);
    }

    public function reviews()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Review::class);
    }

    public function profile()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Profile::class);
    }

    public function approvedVenues()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Venue::class)->where('is_approved', '=', 1);
    }

    public function unapprovedVenues()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Venue::class)->where('is_approved', false);
    }

    public function ownVenuesReviews()
    {
        return $this->reviews()->whereIn('user_id', function($query) {
            $query->select('id')
            ->from('venues')
            ->whereRaw('venues.user_id = users.id');
        })->get();
    }
}
```

**Venue Model:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Venue extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id',
        'city_id',
        'category_id',
        'title',
        'address',
        'phone',
        'email',
        'website',
        'facebook',
        'instagram',
        'content_bg',
        'content_en',
        'cover_image',
        'lat',
        'lng'
    ];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
    }

    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class, 'category_id');
    }

    public function city()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(City::class, 'city_id');
    }

    public function features()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Feature::class, 'venue_feature');
    }

    public function images()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(VenueImage::class);
    }

    public function reviews()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Review::class);
    }
}
```

**Review Model:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Review extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = ['rating', 'content', 'venue_id', 'user_id'];

    public function venue()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Venue::class);
    }

    public function images()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ReviewImage::class);
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

So Users have many Venues, Venues have many reviews.

I want to get reviews on own Venues for example (If I own venues with id 100, 101 - I want to get all reviews for these two venues)

**Raw query is this:**

```
SELECT * FROM `reviews` WHERE reviews.venue_id IN (SELECT venues.id FROM venues WHERE venues.user_id = 1)
```

**What I tried in Laravel in User model (doesn't work), I'm also curious if there is a way, without raw part:**

```
public function ownVenuesReviews()
{
    return $this->reviews()->whereIn('user_id', function($query) {
        $query->select('id')
        ->from('venues')
        ->whereRaw('venues.user_id = users.id');
    })->get();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [`HasManyThrough` relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through) should work, if I'm understanding your model relationships properly:

```
public function ownVenueReviews(): HasManyThrough
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Review::class, Venue::class);
}
```

Comment: It works somehow

Answer (score 0):

The raw part is only needed because you have to include the foreign key in the select portion of the sub query. Even though you may not want the user_id in the query result it must still be selected for Laravel to be able to make the relationship match work.

```
public function ownVenuesReviews()
{
    return $this->reviews()->whereIn('user_id', function($query) {
        $query->select('id', 'user_id')
        ->from('venues');
    })->get();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I already tried something like this, but I found two things. First of all is the error `Operand should contain 1 column(s) ` and second is that `$this->reviews()` is something like "SELECT * FROM reviews where user_id = 1` So .. it returns all reviews of user. I want to get all reviews on own venues (check example from the question) Idea is to get all users reviews on own venues.

Comment: You're creating an `IN()` clause with a subquery that returns multiple columns; that isn't going to work. Try calling `toSql()` method instead of `get()` and see what's returned.

Answer (score 0):

I did it like this, but I'm not quite sure, that this is the best way, I'm open to suggestions:

```
public function ownVenuesReviews()
{
    return Review::whereIn('venue_id', function($query) {
        $query->select('id')
        ->from('venues')
        ->where('user_id', $this->id);
    })->get();
}
```